# Using Header Variables for User Authentication

Tags: azure, http-headers, azure-active-directory

I am not sure if I am asking this question correctly or not, but if a user is authenticated through MS Azure, can Azure send the identity of the user to another system through HTTP header variable?
If so, what if the HTTP server on the other system is Apache based and not IIS. Is it still possible? If yes, how is it done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest option available in the Azure AD offerings is [Header based SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on#header-based-sso).

> Header-based single sign-on works for applications that use HTTP
>   headers for authentication. This sign-on method uses a third-party
>   authentication service called PingAccess. A user only needs to
>   authenticate to Azure AD.

If you could expand your question a bit more, maybe we can help with a better answer

Comment: We have 2 different applications, one is Salesforce and the other is Siebel. Salesforce uses Azure as the identity to perform SSO using SAML .Once the user is logged into Salesforce, it should be able to access the Siebel web without be prompted for userid / password. However the version of our Siebel doesn’t support SAML, therefore can’t act as a service provider.One solution is if the user is already authenticated to Azure, then Azure can send identity of the user to Siebel through HTTP header variable and from there Siebel can allow the user to access the application.

Comment: Also one question was can Azure send this information to non-IIS web server?

Answer (score 1):

So the flow as I understand is like follows..

1. Salesforce redirects the user to Azure AD
2. Azure AD authenticates the user (uses SAML) and sends the SAML token back to salesForce
3. The user who signed in to SalesForce now redirects to a Siebel App?
4. The expectation is that the user would not have to authenticate again for Siebel?

The quick answer is that Azure AD will authenticate the user using header-based, SAML or OpenID only if the Siebel app is registered with Azure AD.

Without registration, Azure AD has no knowledge about this app (Siebel) and wont deal with it.

During registration, Siebel developers can choose if they want to use SAML, header based or OpenId for authentication and Azure AD will automatically Single sign-on an already signed in user (like in this example the user has already signed-in to SalesForce) to Siebel and wont prompt the user for credentials.